# jquery gets the old value from the modal textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jquery modal that is displayed for getting user's comment when the user clicks on the reject button in the page.

The problem is when I type some comment and confirm the reject button in the modal, I cant get the value of the commenting textarea. when I reload the page, and do this process again, I get the value of the textarea before I had reloaded the page.

Here is the jquery functions:

```
$("#rejectBtnHOD").on('click', function(){
    $("#modal-container-522009").modal(); // Displays modal well
});

$(document).on("click", "#confirmRejection", function(){
    var vid = "<?php echo $fields['vid']; ?>"; // getting the request id well
    var rejComment = $('body').find('#comment').val(); // cant get the value of textarea

    alert(rejComment); return false;
});
```

HTML code (modal):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-container-522009" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Leave a comment!
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 300px;">
                <textarea id="comment" class="col-md-12" style="height: 200px;" ></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> <button id="confirmRejection" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

BTW, If I replace the `<textarea>` tag with an `<input type="text">`, it works just fine!

Comment: Your code seems to work okay in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omuswtkp/)

Comment: Yes, as in that fiddle, the code works fine if I am not trying to get the value of he textarea from the page and not the modal.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a text area you have to do

```
$("#ID").html()
```

since you're getting the value between the XML labels.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var rejComment = $('#comment').val();
```